# Display empty field when backend not return data

Tags: angular

I have a http service the get data from the backend for display in a material field in the frontend.

controler.ts

```
import { Job } from '../models/job.model'; //this is my interface model

export class JobComponent {

  public jobData = <Job>{};
  public data$: Observable<Job>;


  // getJobs is a simple method that make a http request to the backend
  this.data$ = this.serviceJob.getJobs(jobId).pipe(
            catchError(error => {
                console.error('Error loading job data: ', error.message);
                return of(this.jobData); // Return a Empty observable when error
            })
  );
}
```

view.html

```
<mat-card *ngIf="(data | async) as data ">
...
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>DBE</mat-label>
    <input matInput [value]="data.dbe" disabled />
  </mat-form-field>
...
</matcard>
```

When `data$` returns empty `{}` the field DBE display `Undefined`. I want to keeping display the field but with a null value. A empty `data$` occurs when the backend don't find data or when there is a exception.

I'm looking for a best approach to avoid to add a ugly `|| null"` in each field. If the backend returns me a empty object of `<Job>`, does solves my problem. But unfortunately I can't change the backend, and this is your default behaviour when don't find any data.

Is there a the best way to solve this?

Comment: you map function to transform result.

Answer (score 0):

You could manipulate the data you get from the API by adding a `map()` into your pipe.

```
  this.data$ = this.serviceJob.getJobs(jobId).pipe(
            map(job => {
               return job || { dbe: '' } as Job;
            }),
            catchError(error => {
                console.error('Error loading job data: ', error.message);
                return of(this.jobData); // Return a Empty observable when error
            })
  );
```

So if the returned value from the API is a falsy value it will pass job object with a empty dbe property

Comment: A empty object already has been returned from the backend when no data. But, when you try to display this empty object `{}` the fields displaying `Undefined`. The only way to avoid this, is if the backend returns something like this: `{ dbe: ''}` for each of this 40 fields, but like I sad, is not possible to change his behaviour.

Comment: @Joel ok that makes sense. I am not sure of the whole format of your Job object, but I'll update the answer. Let me know if it works out for you